# SQL Server - determining statement starting time from within trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, sql-server-2016

I'm trying to find a good solution for one task problem can't find a good one yet. So my question is - is it possible to get 'statement starting time' inside the trigger context. Basically, the starting time of update (insert, delete) which caused trigger to fire?

I've tried a few data management views, like [`sys.dm_tran_active_transactions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-tran-active-transactions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2016), [`sys.dm_exec_requests`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-requests-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2016) and couple of others.
I can get the starting time of the full SQL batch, or starting time of the transaction from the views I mentioned (using current @@spid), but can't find starting time of 'trigger firing statement'

Do you know if it's even possible in SQL Server?

Comment: You may want to try asking this in dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getdate()` functiuon in your trigger like:

```
select getdate() 
from inserted i
```

Comment: actually I cannot. This is not 'starting time', this is more of an 'ending time' of the statement which caused trigger to fire. Also, no reason to use `inserted` table here